# The right way to read a circuit

Tags: logic-gates

I can easily understand these simple circuits:

[image]

or

[image]

but I can't wrap my head around this:

[image]

Not (A AND B) is all I get, **but there is still a logical sum at the end (OR) and I have no idea where to put it**

but for this, I can understand:

Not (A AND B)

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you hoping to understand the truth table for that particular circuit? Or a description of how logic gates work? Or a symbolic equation like ((A AND B) OR (NOT B))?

Comment: (A&B) OR (NOT B)?

Comment: @DanLaks I'm trying to learn how to understand the circuit so I can write down the correct logic or symbolic equation like you said

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find it helpful to work right to left. The last gate is an OR gate. Forget about what the actual inputs are for the moment. They're just two inputs. Let's call them X and Y.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Ye9b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now let's look at the X input. You already appear to understand that it is (A AND B), so let's substitute that in for X:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5EV8u.png)</sup>

Obviously, input Y is nothing more than (NOT B), so substitute that in for Y:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8RYMl.png)</sup>

And that's it.

Comment: this is brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

You just need to take it one gate at a time.  The output of the AND gate is

A AND B

The output of the inverter is simply

NOT B

so the output of the OR gate, which is X, is

X = (A AND B) OR (NOT B)

**This can be reduced to just two gates:**

By the distributive law (**T3** [on this page](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/)), the above equation is the same as:

X = (A OR NOT B) AND (B OR NOT B)

**The second term cancels out, since it is always 1, so you are just left with:**

**X = A OR NOT B**

[image]

BTW if you go to [WolframAlpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), and type "simplify (A AND B) OR (NOT B)" you'll get the same answer.  But I wanted to explain why.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm aware of redundancy laws, I was just having trouble understanding the circuits!!!

Answer (score 1):

B goes to two gates, so you need to use it twice. One of them is ANDed with A (`A AND B`), the other is inverted (`NOT B`). Both are then ORed together (`(A AND B) OR NOT B`).